# What are the total number of state combinations for this dice game?

Tags: probability-theory, permutations, combinations

Lets say we have the dice game explained below. What are the total number of game states? In other words, how many numerical combinations of lives, totalScore, and scratchScore exist?

**Initial State:**

lives = 5, totalScore = 0, scratchScore = 0

**The Rules:**

Each turn you roll a 6-sided dice. If the roll is [1-5] then you add that score to your scratchScore. If you roll a 6, then your scratchScore is reset to 0 and you lose 1 life.

Before each roll, you may decided to yell "BANK" at which point you add your scratchScore to your totalScore and reset the scratchScore to 0. Everytime you yell "BANK" though you will lose 1 life.

If lives=0 you lose. Otherwise youc an win by achieving a totalScore that is >= 40. The idea is to only yell "BANK" when your scratchScore is somewhat large.

**Here is an example game:**

1. lives = 5; total score = 0; scratch score = 0.
   You roll a 2 and do **not** yell ”bank.”
2. lives = 5; total score = 0; scratch score = 2.
   You roll a 3 and do **not** yell ”bank.”
3. lives = 5; total score = 0; scratch score = 5.
   You roll a 4 and yell ”bank.”
4. lives = 4; total score = 9; scratch score = 0.
   You roll a 2 and do **not** yell ”bank.”
5. lives = 4; total score = 9; scratch score = 2.
   You roll a 6.
6. lives = 3; total score = 9; scratch score = 0
7. ... repeat untill lives=0 or totalScore >= 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will note L=Lives , T=Total Score and S=Scratch Score.

*There are probably some errors, it is just a plan, and you can check step by step if you agree or not.*

$L$ can be $0$ to $5$.

If $L=0$ , we are not interested with other values, I consider we can count all cases with $L=0$ as only 1 case.

For all other values for $L$ (from 0 to 5) :

- $T$ can be from $0$ to $39$ (even if $T=1$ or $2$ or $3$ seems stupid)
- $S$ can be from $0$ to $39-T$

So , when T=0, we have 40 different values possible for S

when T=1, we have 39 different values possible for S... total number is 40+39+.  +1 =420

When L=5, we are limited to T=0, so 40 different values for S.
and when L<5 , we can have all mix for T and S

And we have a final case : Win : the player wins.
So total $=40+ 420 \times 4 +1+1$

Many values are stupid.

For example, if L=5, S=38 and T=0 : very strange ; probably the player should have yelled 'bank'.